# For loop in batch file error: Do was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to execute following command using batch file:

```
for /f %i in (D:\random\servers.txt) DO (d:\utils\tail -60 \\%i\c$\Windows\windowsUpdate.log | d:\utils\grep "updates detected" & set tx1234=%i)
```

It works when being invoked on its own in command prompt but as soon as I would save it within batch file it fails with the message

> Do was unexpected at this time

Any ideas?

Comment: in batch use %%i, whereas in command line use %i

Comment: @kayasax, your comment is the answer I'd vote up.

Comment: @PA made a answer, thanks

Answer (score 13):

in batch use `%%i`, whereas in command line use `%i`

Comment: The answer is correct but what is the explanation for why this is different or at least the definition of what is different that causes this between batch and command line?