# Error variable unexpected when executing my cmd file

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

The issue is that when I put this line inside cmd file it doesn't work and I have an error on command line window

```
for /F "tokens=*" %i in (dir /S /B *.log) do del %i
```

Error :

```
Unexpected variable i (translated from french because I have french windows)
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [For loop in batch file error: Do was unexpected at this time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726011/for-loop-in-batch-file-error-do-was-unexpected-at-this-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /S /B *.log') do del "%%i"
                  ^^      ^               ^         ^^^ ^
```

- Percent signs in `for` replaceable parameters should be escaped inside batch files, replacing the single `%` with `%%`.
- To execute a command with a `for /f`, you need to enclose the command with single quotes or, if the command itself contains single quotes, with backquotes and include the `usebackq` clause in the `for /f` options.
- It is better to quote the file references to avoid problems with spaces or special characters

Anyway, this command can be written as

```
del /s *.log
```

instead of executing a `del` operation for each file.

Answer (score 0):

From command line:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /S /B *.log') do del "%~i"
```

or if used in a batch:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /S /B *.log') do del "%%~i"
```

Explanation:

- surround `dir /S /B *.log` with single quotes;
- enclose file name in double quotes as follows `del "%~i"` as it could contain spaces...

**Resources** (required reading):

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all of you for your helps. Please excuse my late answer.

Here is the solution I've finally adopted thanks to @MC ND

```
del /s *.log
del /s *.log0*
del /s *.tlog
rmdir /S /Q wls-admin\.wlnotdelete
rmdir /S /Q wls-myapp\.wlnotdelete
```